# My tableViewCells not created?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am working on JSON, in my program my tableView delegate methods called first, then i am getting data from server successfully, but i want to create rows in tableView based upon number of records what we get from server. How ?

My code is.....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.displayDataTableView.delegate = self;
self.displayDataTableView.dataSource = self;


self.dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

self.urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
self.urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"My host name"]];
self.dataTask = [self.urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:self.urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSMutableDictionary *serverRes = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    //        NSLog(@"...%@ ", serverRes);

    self.integer = [[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] count];
    NSLog(@"************* = %lu", self.integer);

    for (int i=0; i<self.integer; i++) {
        [self.dateArray addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Date"]];
        [self.amountArray addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"TotalAmount"]];


    }

    NSLog(@"Date Array : %@", self.dateArray);

}];

[self.dataTask resume];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return self.integer;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}else{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailsTitle" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    return cell;


}
}
```

Can any one do help.....

Comment: Just reload the tableView in mainQueue once you got the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check empty cell and create new cell using same identifier

```
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"detailsCell"];
        }
        return cell;
    }else{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailsTitle" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"detailsTitle"];
        }


        return cell;


    }
```

Or  reload tableview while getting data from server

```
     self.integer = [[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] count];
        NSLog(@"************* = %lu", self.integer);

        for (int i=0; i<self.integer; i++) {
            [self.dateArray addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Date"]];
            [self.amountArray addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"TotalAmount"]];

        }
[tblview reloadData];
```

Comment: No, it's not created any cell.

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
    return self.integer;
}

Comment: I am passing  return self.integer; this, but self.integer value can get after calling above delegate method.

Comment: try now another answer

Comment: it is another problem . you need to check your internet connection and server side code.

Answer (score 1):

`UITableView` is already created when land on this view so you need to reload `UITableView` after getting a result from the server.

```
self.integer = [[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] count];
NSLog(@"************* = %lu", self.integer);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.displayDataTableView reloadData];
    });
```

This is the right solution for me....

Comment: Bro it's reloaded successfully.. but it's take some time to create cells, i am getting data from server immediately...

Comment: It's showing this message on console...This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.
 Stack:(

Comment: ` if (!cell) { \\code \\ }` use this for creating cell.

Comment: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
  // Do stuff to UI
}` add your server call inside this to step out to the main thread in order to call reloadData

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.displayDataTableView.delegate = self;
self.displayDataTableView.dataSource = self;


self.dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

self.urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
self.urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"API Name"]];
self.dataTask = [self.urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:self.urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSMutableDictionary *serverRes = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    //        NSLog(@"...%@ ", serverRes);

    self.integer = [[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] count];
    NSLog(@"************* = %lu", self.integer);

    for (int i=0; i<self.integer; i++) {
        [self.dateArray addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Date"]];
        [self.amountArray addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"TotalAmount"]];


    }

    NSLog(@"Date Array : %@", self.dateArray);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.displayDataTableView reloadData];
});
}];

[self.dataTask resume];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return self.integer;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}else{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailsTitle" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    return cell;


}
}
```